# Remove scroll bars from Jquery Mobile during page transition

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, transition

I'm writing an application using JQuery mobile targeted for Android tablets (I'm testing on Honeycomb Android 3.0). When I transition from page to page using the slide transition, DURING the transition I see scroll bars. Before and after the transition the scroll bars go away. I've attempted to use:

```
html { overflow: hidden; }

body { overflow: hidden; }

* { overflow: hidden; }

.ui-page { overflow: hidden; }
```

However, none of these work. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm getting very fed up with Android and JQuery mobile. I even wrapped the Jquery mobile pages in a native Android WebView and I still have similar issues. Ugh! I went this route initially in order to save time but now I'm thinking I should have went native from the beginning.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

Ok so after not being able to remove the scroll bars with JavaScript, I tried doing so in Java. I did the following:

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.coWebView);
    wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

This would seem obvious, however the scroll bars do not display without this anyway - my issue was removing them during transitions. This does however get rid of (for me at least - on Android Honeycomb tablet) the vertical scroll bars during transitions. I do however still see a horizontal scroll bar of about 1px in height...but it's better than it was.

Answer (score 0):

I add this in the java files; my cordova version is 4.0.Now the scroll bar disappear.

```
super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

the full code of the function like that :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    ///////
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```